# The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start

Tags: azure-functions

While running a simple Timer Trigger Azure Function locally, I'm getting below error.

I create new Azure Functions project with timer trigger using Visual Studio 2019.

I have Azure development Workload installed.
[image: Azure development Workload installed]

Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/12 * * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
[2021-11-24T15:45:29.878Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start.
[2021-11-24T15:45:29.880Z] The listener for function 'Function1' was unable to start. Azure.Storage.Blobs: Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
RequestId:3bb00ada-83ec-4685-987b-5d4b51cb39db
Time:2021-11-24T15:45:29.5583585Z
[2021-11-24T15:45:29.880Z] Status: 500 (Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.)
[2021-11-24T15:45:29.881Z] ErrorCode: InternalError
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59026924/6119878) suggests to disable the firewall. It seems firewall is the issue for me also. When disabling firewall is not an option, is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/SlNlJg6.png - could you please check and let know the azure storage emulator is installed in your system!

Comment: Yes. It is installed

Comment: could you please mention your function code, the packages you installed like azure functions core tools version, language (.net, python) version, VS Code or Visual Studio you're using?, what are the extensions you have installed If it is VS Code or Visual Studio and the steps how you're following to run?

Comment: Updated code and steps. Same code is working fine in different machine which doesn't have any firewall restrictions.

Comment: Have you installed azure functions core tools and what is your .net version using in azure functions?

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-local, Visual Studio 2019 Azure development workload includes Core Tools for local testing. I'm using .Net Core 3.1

Comment: It started working after changing "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" to "AzureWebJobsStorage": "none". Not sure why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all the discussions, glad that your issue got resolved.

Here is my solution to help the other community members as tested in my local environment:

Below is the code:

local.settings.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
    }
}
```

Function1.cs

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace KrishTimerTriggerNetCore31
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static void Run([TimerTrigger("*/12 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

When you created the azure functions project in Visual Studio with timer trigger template, by default your `local.settings.json` file contains this value  `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"`

If the `UseDevelopmentStorage` to `none`, then the same error will occurs:

[image]

Make Sure all required applications are installed and up to date for your requirement like Azure Functions Core Tools Version, Azure Storage emulator (locally), .Net Core Runtime Versions and SDKs and the extensions while installing Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks, It works on my end. What I did to fixed the issue was re-installed the Azure Storage emulator (locally) from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#get-the-storage-emulator. And it resolves the issue

Answer (score 4):

Recently, I also encountered the error in *Visual Studio 2022*.

The solution:

1-Download and install the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer.
On the [download page](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/storage/storage-explorer/) select your operating system from the drop-down menu.

2-With Visual Studio Open, and with the Azure function set as Startup Project, Open the Azure Storage Explorer by typing its name in the Windows start menu.

3-In the left menu, expand Storage Accounts -> (Emulator - Default Ports) (key) -> Blob Containers. Then left-click on azure-webjobs-hosts and select Delete.

4- Restart the Visual Studio. Everything should work now.

References:
[Cameron Dwyer blog](https://camerondwyer.com/2022/07/22/how-to-fix-azure-functions-timer-trigger-unable-to-start-running-locally-with-vs2022-17-2-x-azurite/)
[Issue on github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/2959)