# How to integrate FastAPI with Azure Functions using both HTTP and Schedule triggers?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, fastapi

I'm using Azure's sample project for fastapi az functions https://github.com/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/tree/main/

And I'd like to create a FastAPI schedule trigger functions additional to my HTTP Trigger functions. What's the best way to achieve this?

```
import fastapi

app = fastapi.FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def index():
    logging.info("Logging from root")
    return {
        "info": "Hello there",
    }

## create another scheduled function here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I have used the below code and it worked for me*

**`Code:`**

```
import  azure.functions  as  func
import  datetime
import  logging
from  WrapperFunction  import  app  as  fastapi_app

import  fastapi

app  =  fastapi.FastAPI()

app  =  func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name(name="mytimer")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 */5 * * * *",
arg_name="mytimer",
run_on_startup=True)
def  test_function(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
utc_timestamp  =  datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
if  mytimer.past_due:
logging.info('The timer is past due!')
logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

Currently my function is getting triggered every 5 mins but you can change the CRON to `0 0 1 * *` to run it once in a month.

**`Output:`**

[image]

Comment: My use case is to use it once a month that's why I wanted to use AZ functions schedule triggers. Do you think its okay if I use your suggestion for my use case too ?

Comment: I have modified my answer, please check. In this way you can run your function once in a month

Comment: any idea why I'm getting this error while starting the app?

[2023-08-21T19:48:46.933Z] The listener for function 'Functions.mytimer' was unable to start.
[2023-08-21T19:48:46.934Z] The listener for function 'Functions.mytimer' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage: Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor.

Comment: it occurs when I try to test locally

Comment: try to start the Azurite in the visual studio code as suggested in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59026572/listener-for-function-was-unable-to-start-azure-function-app-timetrigger/67008655#67008655 SO thread, it will work. Don't forget to set "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" in your local setting file

Comment: Thank you for your help. One more question were you able to deploy it and has it worked?
I tried to deploy it but its says "Http Triggers not found" 
It works fine locally though