# Python FASTAPI az functions working locally but not when deployed

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, fastapi

I have developed a Python FastAPI Azure Function that includes both HTTP-triggered and timer-scheduled triggers. I followed this Azure sample code to create the FastAPI Python Azure Function: [Azure Functions Python Create FastAPI App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/fastapi-on-azure-functions/azure-functions-python-create-fastapi-app/). Additionally, I implemented the timer-scheduled trigger using the code suggested in this GitHub issue: [Azure/azure-functions-python-worker#1284](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/1284).

Everything works fine when tested locally, but upon deploying to Azure Functions, an error occurs stating 'HTTP trigger not found'.

Here are my application settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could deploy the ***FastAPI function*** to Azure Function App created with ***App Service Plan***.

**Steps followed:**

- Created a Fast API Azure function with both Http and Timer Triggers.

**My function Code:**

Thanks [@Ikhtesam Afrin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76945301/19991670) for the code.

```py
app = fastapi.FastAPI()

app = func.AsgiFunctionApp(app=fastapi_app, http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.function_name(name="mytimer")
@app.schedule(schedule="* 1 * * * *", 
              arg_name="mytimer",
              run_on_startup=True) 
def test_function(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)
```

**Local Response:**

[image]

- I tried to *deploy my fast API application* to ***Azure Function app with Consumption plan***, but couldn't *sync the triggers after deployment*.

[image]

**Instead, you can deploy your  FastAPI function to Function App with App Service Plan**

- I have created a **Python Function App** with **App Service Plan**:

**Application Settings:**

[image]

- ***Deployed application using function core tools with command:***

```
func azure functionapp publish <function_app_name>
```

[image]

[image]

- Able to see the **deployed function triggers** in the `Portal=>Function App`.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Http Function:**

[image]

**Timer Function:**

[image]

Comment: Were you able to deploy it using azure devops cause Im getting an error as follows:

Comment: ##[error]Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
##[warning]Can't find loc string for key: KuduStackTraceURL
##[error]KuduStackTraceURL https://$test-linux-function-app:***@test-linux-function-app.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/vfs/LogFiles/kudu/trace
##[error]Error: Error: Failed to deploy web package to App Service. Service Unavailable (CODE: 503)
Successfully added release annotation to the Application Insight : test-app-insights-test
##[warning]Error: Failed to update deployment history. Error: Service Unavailable (CODE: 503)

Comment: I didnt try with Azure devops, but deployed using command line.